# Openshift cannot create any pods

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift

I am testing a openshift v3 starter (ca-central-1) and created a project from custom docker image stream (from github). It was running fine, but after I changed a config map, rescaled the deployment to 0 pods, upscaled it to 1 pod, openshift can no longer start any pods.

The error in web interface is (in Events tab):

```
Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to start sandbox container 
for pod "hass-19-98vws": Error response from daemon: grpc: the connection is unavailable.

Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
```

These messages appear in a endless loop. I tried to deploy new deployment but it gives same logs.
What am I doing wring?

Comment: Which OpenShift cluster are you using? Some of the OpenShift clusters have been having progressive upgrades done over past few days. You may be getting affected by that. https://status.starter.openshift.com/

Comment: It's ca-central-1 (I also updated question text). If this is the case, can I trust all-green historical status of cluster? (Notification says that upgrades started on march 26 which is several days ago)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems that I was affected by an upgrade of cluster. The issue resolved itself after a 2 days.